# How to create custom search place in Wordpress with php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a custom search to search and find the result. I have defined the results and I really want to create a `switch`. I have some defined `case`s with an id, I want to search that id in the search place, and show the results. I have ids and results, I just want to create search place, and when someone searches a special id, then the search result shows that id's properties that I have defined it from past in data base or anywhere else.

Do you have any special idea to implement this? Or if wordpress has any special plugin to do something like this, introduce it to me.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-autocomplete/screenshots/

under setting define your id of custom search